# Creating animation in Google Earth using png overlays with kml timestamps

Tags: kml, google-earth, animation, overlay

I have the following kml files, each with a different timestamp and png:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
 xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
 <GroundOverlay>
 <name>gx:LatLonQuad Example</name>
 <Icon>
<href>
/Users/asd/Dropbox/0mylayerExport.png
</href>
 </Icon>
<gx:LatLonQuad>
<coordinates>
-71.007186998722,42.2869344810739 -70.9807964189347,42.360133347777 -71.1410513483055,42.3916360561188 -71.1680083772048,42.3178859041619
</coordinates>
<TimeStamp>
<when>1944-06-06T06:2010-10-26T06:30:08
></when></TimeStamp><rotation>100</rotation>
</gx:LatLonQuad>
</GroundOverlay>
</kml>
```

What I'm trying to do is to animate the sequence of png overlays, but I can't figure out how.

I can view all of the kml files in google earth, and click through them manually, but is there a neater way of animating this, instead of ticking them on and off?

---

I have tried manually adding timestamps, and time intervals in google-earth, and am still failing to automatically animate overlays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is your time span.  Its supposed to be in the format
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:sszzzzzz (see [KML Ref](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#timestamp))

"1944-06-06T06:2010-10-26T06:30:08
"

is wrong in the "mm" part. Also, if you're trying to animate a set of time periods rather than points, you need timestamp rather than span.

Time should be before  and after  according to the documentation although I'm not sure if that actually matters in KML.

PNG makes the output KMZ large (or takes longer to download if you leave them out there on the web), so it is best to convert to jpg (if an image) or gif (if a simple cartoon/icon).